# Google Cloud Configuration CPUs

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, vcpu

I need to configure a machine on Google Cloud Platform (Brazil/Sao Paulo) to run a biometric service and my software provider requested a machine with the following specification:

```
        "2 x Intel® Xeon® Gold 6138 Processor 20-core CPU, 128 GB RAM"
```

Is it correct/equivalent, selecting:

```
Series: N1 (Powered by Intel Skylake CPU platform or one of its predecessors)
Machine type: Custom
 - Cores: 20 vCPUs
 - Memory: 128 GB
```

Should I select on CPU platform: "Automatic" or "Intel Broadwell or later"

If this configuration is not equivalent with requested, what configuration best fit with it?

Thanks in advance,

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 6138's CPUs are marked as
"Products formerly Skylake" at the official [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/codename/37572/skylake.html) page .
That is why the usage of "Series: N1 (Powered by Intel Skylake CPU platform or one of its predecessors)" is correct assumption here.

[Google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms) says that:

> If you do not actively specify a CPU platform, the instance uses the default platform for the zone where the instance will run. For a list of zones and their default CPU platforms, see [Regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/). Additionally, each CPU platform is available only for specific machine types.
>
> On Compute Engine, each virtual CPU (vCPU) is implemented as a single hardware hyper-thread on one of the available CPU platforms.

From what I see Skylake is available for instances of "n1" type and some "m1" (m1-megamem only).

Regarding the "`Automatic` vs `Intel Broadwell or later`" [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform) says that:

> Any newly created VM without a minimum CPU specification will get the default CPU Platform automatically.

When you create an instance in a zone, your instance will use the default processor supported in that zone. For example, if you create an instance in the us-central1-a zone, your instance by default uses a Haswell processor, unless you specify another option.

As you can see (depending on the zone) you can end up with CPU of different architecture if you select "Automatic" option.

So, by explicitly selecting the platform you can be sure that it won't be changed after VM restart, etc.

Hope that helps.

Useful resources:

- https://ark.intel.com/
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform/

Comment: Nick, 

Thanks a lot for your response. It was very usefull!